# Accessing Moq Mock Data from DbContext disappears when called twice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to understand a behavior that is occurring in my application. I have mocked out my `DbContext` and when I make a call get items from the `dbContext.Set<T>().ToList()`, the second call does not contain my mocked data. I am not sure why this happens since that data should still exist. Please see code below:

SUT:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDb
    : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDb()
    {

    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

UNIT TEST:

```
public class MockDatabase
{
    public Mock<EmployeeDb> SetMockData()
    {
        var mockDb = new Mock<EmployeeDb>();

        mockDb.Setup(i => i.Set<Employee>()).Returns(GetMockSet(Employees).Object);
        mockDb.SetupGet(i => i.Employees).Returns(() => GetMockSet(Employees).Object);

        return mockDb;
    }
    private List<Employee> _providers;
    private List<Employee> Employees => _providers ?? (_providers = new List<Employee>
    {
        GetEmployee(1),
        GetEmployee(2),
        GetEmployee(3),
        GetEmployee(4),
        GetEmployee(5),
    });
    private static Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        return new Employee
        {
            FirstName = Faker.Name.First(),
            LastName = Faker.Name.Last(),
            Age = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(50),
            Id = id,
            Salary = Faker.RandomNumber.Next(100000)
        };
    }

    #region Hood

    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetMockSet<T>(IList<T> items) where T : class
    {
        var querable = items.AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(querable.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(querable.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(querable.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(querable.GetEnumerator());
        mockSet.Setup(i => i.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback(delegate (T item) {
            items.Add(item);
        });
        return mockSet;
    }

    #endregion
}


[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private EmployeeDb _context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        var mockDb = new MockDatabase();
        _context = mockDb.SetMockData().Object;
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_CallTwice_ReturnsEqualCount()
    {
        var emps = _context.Set<Employee>().ToList();
        var emps2 = _context.Set<Employee>().ToList();

        Assert.IsTrue(emps.Count == emps2.Count);

        // -- This works
        //var empCount = _context.Set<Employee>().Count();
        //var empCount2 = _context.Set<Employee>().Count();

        //Assert.IsTrue(empCount == empCount2);
    }
}
```

Is there something I am not getting about this code? Is there something Moq does with the `ToList()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToList` enumerates the set when invoked, but the enumerator is forward only, so after the first call it is already at the end.

When setting up the `GetEnumerator` use the function overload of the `Returns` in order to allow multiple calls other wise the same enumerator will be returned every time and you get the behavior you experienced.

```
mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => querable.GetEnumerator()); //<-- function
```